# R get one value according to some rules in each group

Tags: r, group-by

I have a dataframe:

```
test = data.frame(short_name = rep(c('a','b','c'),each = 3),full_name = c('apple','ahora','aixin','bike','beber','boai','cerrar','cat','caocao'))
```

which like:

```
short_name   full_name
    a         apple
    a         ahora
    a         aixin
    b         bike
    b         beber
    b         boai
    c         cerrar
    c         cat
    c         caocao
```

I want to based on short_name as a group to get a value from the full_name, it can be:

1) get the first element(first row of that group), in my case that would be:

```
short_name   full_name
    a         apple
    b         bike
    c         cerrar
```

2) get a random element from full_name

3) get a element according to some rules,in my case you may notice they are just three different languages: English,spanish and chinese; I may put a function here tell me what languages it origins and pick say spanish for each group as the full_name of the shortcut,however that function is irrelevant to this topic so I just want to get the shortest one from each group, and the tie break rule is always get the first one in that group if they are of the same length,the result should be:

```
short_name   full_name
    a         apple
    b         bike
    c         cat
```

you can use any package(data.table,dplyr,etc) or self-write method, I want to see different solution and get the most efficient and elegant one

According to recent answers, my calculation based on big data(8 million records) are:

```
library(tictoc)
library(dplyr)
tic("dplyr slice1")
sale_data_detail_ly_slice1<-sale_data_detail_ly %>% group_by(prod_id) %>% slice(1)
toc()
dplyr slice1: 26.966 sec elapsed

tic("data.table")
sale_data_detail_ly_slice1 = sale_data_detail_ly[,.SD[1,],by = prod_id]
toc()
data.table: 501.416 sec elapsed
```

I could see a big difference

Answer (score 2):

We can do a group by 'short_name' andd get the first row with `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% 
   group_by(short_name) %>%
   slice(1)
```

---

Or to get random element

```
test %>%
  group_by(short_name) %>%
  slice(sample(row_number(), 1))
```

---

If it is the shortest one

```
test %>%
   group_by(short_name) %>%
   slice(which.min(nchar(as.character(full_name))))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   short_name [3]
#  short_name full_name
#  <fct>      <fct>    
#1 a          apple    
#2 b          bike     
#3 c          cat
```

---

Or using `summarise`

```
test %>%
    group_by(short_name) %>%
    summarise(full_name = first(full_name))

test %>%
    group_by(short_name) %>%
    summarise(full_name = sample(full_name, 1))
```

---

With `data.table`, the options are

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test)[test[, .I[1], .(short_name)]$V1]
setDT(test)[test[, .I[sample(seq_len(.N), 1)], .(short_name)]$V1]
```

Comment: The data.table solution is slow than dplyr, which surprised me.

Comment: @cloudscomputes  The `.I` should be faster.  BTW, how big is the dataset you compared to

Comment: It has 8,000,000 records

Comment: @cloudscomputes  Anyway, the `.I` method would be faster than `.SD`.  From my previous benchmarks, it should be faster than `slice`, but if you say the opposite, I am no party to oppose that view

Answer (score 2):

As long as you can figure out how to calculate the value you want within each group, you can do any kind of selection with `group_by` and `summarise`. Doing them all in one go:

```
test %>%
    group_by(short_name) %>%
    summarise(
        first = first(full_name),
        random = sample(full_name, 1),
        # as.character needed here because full_name is currently
        #   a factor
        shortest = full_name[which.min(nchar(as.character(full_name)))]
    )
```

Comment: summarise(random = sample(full_name, 1)) is very time consuming for large data sets, it takes hours to calculate a table with 8 million records and it is still running

Comment: `random = full_name[sample.int(n(), 1)]` might be faster, the exact performance would depend on the size of the groups.

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` solution slightly different from @akrun's:

```
test[, .SD[1,], by = short_name]

test[, .SD[sample(.N, 1),], by = short_name]

test[, .SD[which.min(nchar(as.character(full_name))),], by = short_name]
```